# Como fazer um scroll para o final de uma div?

Tags: jquery, css, rolamento

Estou querendo que uma determinada `div`, que possua o atributo `overflow-y:auto`, cuja altura é fixa, seja rolada ao final, assim que um elemento é acrescentado nela.

Nesse caso, preciso que ela role até o final, pelo fato de sua altura ser fixa, porém não é fixa a quantidade de elementos dentro dela. Ou seja, assim que um elemento é adicionado com um `append`, preciso que o `scroll` role até o final dessa `div`.

Atualmente, consigo fazer isso facilmente com a função `scrollTop`, porém acho que definir o valor como `9999999` seja <del>muita gambiarra</del> muito deselegante.

Veja algo aproximado do que tenho:

```js
$(function()
{
  $('#div').animate({scrollTop: 9999999}, 500);
});
```

```css
#div{
  
   height:150px;
   background: tomato;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
  <li>Conteúdo</li>
</div>
```

- Como faço para rolar essa `div` até o final, sem ter que utilizar o método atual descrito acima?
- Como saber o tamanho do `scroll` dessa div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente usar o [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), que é uma propriedade apenas leitura que dá a medida do conteúdo do elemento:

```
var div = $('#div')[0];
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/270628/1267304) e [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lv29w75/).

Usando *apenas* jQuery:

```
var div = $('#div');
div.prop("scrollTop", div.prop("scrollHeight"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lv29w75/1/).

Comment: Pra ficar "mais jQuery", será que eu posso utilizar o `prop` para não ter que acessar os elementos assim?

Comment: Sim, pode: ```$('#div').scrollTop($('#div').prop("scrollHeight"));```

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lv29w75/1/

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não sei, não vejo essa prática por aqui nem no SO gringo. Geralmente é colocado apenas no link e no caso o MDN é confiável.

Comment: Ok, e obrigado pela resposta :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mesmo assim, coloquei um resuminho.

Comment: Esse resumindo já dá um grau. As vezes uma explicação longa é ignorada por quem está querendo aprender (principalmente eu)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$('#div').animate({scrollTop: $('#div')[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/raftelti/pen/EVxQXL

Comment: O OP realmente usou `animate`, boa observação.